# What is the concept of two series commutes with each other?

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series

What is the concept of two series commutes with each other?

For example let, $f(x)=\sum a_n x^n$ and $g(x)=\sum b_n y^n$, then how do we commute $f$ ad $g$?

If just like the concept of composition of function, then we have
$$ f(x) \circ g(x)=\sum a_n (\sum b_n y)^n=\sum b_n (\sum a_n x)^n=g(x) \circ f(x).  $$

Is it the concept of ''commutes of series" ?

But how it is true or can be verified?

Comment: Are you talking about formal series? Are the coefficients elements of some ring?

Comment: Commutativity is a property that an *operation* on two objects can have, not the two objects themselves. So one could ask whether composition of power series is commutative (it turns out not to be), but not whether the power series themselves are commutative.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin, yes exactly in the context of formal power series or formal group laws.  Also have concept of Commutant Monoid of a formal power series $f$. Can you please answer?

Comment: @greg-martin The question is whether $f$ and $g$ commute for the composition, which makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f = \sum a_n x^n$ and $g = \sum b_n x^n$ be two formal series. Then
$$
f \circ g = \sum a_n g(x)^n = \sum a_n \left(\sum b_k x^k \right)^n
$$
Now, since
$$
\left(\sum b_k x^k \right)^n = \sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} b_{i_1} \dotsm b_{i_k} x^n
$$
one gets
$$
f \circ g = \sum a_n \left(\sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} b_{i_1} \dotsm b_{i_k}\right)x^n
$$
Therefore $f$ and $g$ commute (for the composition) if and only if, for all $n$,
$$
a_n \left(\sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} b_{i_1} \dotsm b_{i_k}\right) = b_n \left(\sum_{i_1 + \dotsm + i_k = n} a_{i_1} \dotsm a_{i_k}\right)
$$

Comment: Yes, that's nice answer

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: You answer nicely few month ago. I want to ask you another similar question. "Suppose I  have a formal power series $f$ knowing its $1$st $10$ terms. Now I want to know $1$st $10$ terms of a formal power series $g$ such that $g \circ f=f \circ g$. Is it possible to write a computer program to get the answer i.e., $g$ ? Can you hint please ?